# SQL GROUPING SETS averages with multiple many-to-many dimensions

Tags: sql, grouping-sets

I have a table of data with the following:

```
User,Platform,Dt,Activity_Flag,Total_Purchases
1,iOS,05/05/2016,1,1
1,Android,05/05/2016,1,2
2,iOS,05/05/2016,1,0
2,Android,05/05/2016,1,2
3,iOS,05/05/2016,1,1
3,Android,06/05/2016,1,3
1,iOS,06/05/2016,1,2
4,Android,06/05/2016,1,2
1,Android,06/05/2016,1,0
3,iOS,07/05/2016,1,2
2,iOS,08/05/2016,1,0
```

I want to do a GROUPING SETS (Platform,Dt,(Platform,Dt),()) aggregation to be able to find for each combination of Platform and Dt the following:

- Total Purchases
- Total Unique Users
- Average Purchases per User **per Day**

The first two are simple as these can be achieved via a sum(Total_Purchases) and count(distinct user) respectively.

The problem I have is with the last metric. The result set should look like this but I don't know how to get the last column to be calculated correctly:

```
Platform,Dt,Total_Purchases,Total_Unique_Users,Average_Purchases_Per_User_Per_Day
Android,05/05/2016,4,2,2.0 
iOS,05/05/2016,2,3,0.7
Android,06/05/2016,5,3,1.7
iOS,06/05/2016,2,1,2.0
iOS,07/05/2016,2,1,2.0
iOS,08/05/2016,0,1,0.0
,05/05/2016,6,3,2.0
,06/05/2016,7,3,2.3
,07/05/2016,1,1,1.0
,08/05/2016,1,1,1.0
Android,,9,4,1.8
iOS,,6,3,1.2
,,15,4,1.6
```

For the first ten rows we see that getting the Average purchase per user per day is a simple division of the first two columns as the dimension in these rows represent a single date only. But when we look at the final 3 rows we see that the division is not the way to achieve the desired result. This is because it needs to take an average for each day in turn to get the overall per day amount.

If this isn't clear please let me know and I'll be happy to explain better. This is my first post on this site!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: just to confirm your logic, do you want `Total Purchases / Total Days / Total Users` Or `SUM( Purchases / Users BY Day) / Total Days` ?

Comment: Hi, it's the second one. So for example, for "Android" I want it to be ((4/2)+(5/3))/2. for "iOS" it should be ((2/3)+(2/1)+(2/1)+(6/3))/4

Comment: It's in Hive QL, sorry not sure how to tag/edit a post I've already posted?